# c# windows form in form as part of the ihm

Tags: c#, winforms

i'm new to Windows forms, i searched but didn't find any answer to my problem.

I have a Form that will be my main Windows, and i want to integrated other form in a specific space of my main window.
To be more precise, i have my MainWindow, the user will select what specific fonctionality he want to access and his choice will load another form in the dedicated space below
(for exemple :
 - a form that manage every user
 - a form that create and manage data
 - etc...

I saw you can "load" other form by setting the parent of the form to anoter, but it's like having a window in a window.
what i'm searching, is more like a "fragment" of a IHM, that still has the class[Design] for personification, but dosen't have the close and other window functionnalities.

Comment: This is what is called MDI forms: [Multiple-Document Interface (MDI) Applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/multiple-document-interface-mdi-applications)

Comment: Here is a little bit easier to understand information (for beginner): http://csharp.net-informations.com/gui/cs-mdi-form.htm

Comment: `I saw you can "load" other form by setting the parent of the form to anoter, but it's like having a window in a window. what i'm searching, is more like a "fragment" of a IHM, that still has the class[Design] for personification, but dosen't have the close and other window functionnalities` when you create your *new forms* set a few window properties to not show that stuff?

Comment: Found this video: [How to use Multiple-Document Interface (MDI) in Windows Forms C#](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-4EYhC9xDHo)

Comment: I would at least consider creating UserObjects. They work like Forms but are actually meant to be hosted by any containers. Forms are not.

Comment: What is the definition of "IHM"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im' really sorry guys, yeah i just had to make my borderstyle none.

Really sorry to made you loose your time, and thanks for the answer

```
 Reports rep = new Reports();
  rep.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
  rep.MdiParent = this;
  rep.Show();
```